# Trying to understand why ReSharper told me expression is always false

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper

I have a conditional I'm writing that's checking three things.

```
if(LoggedInMembershipUser == null || obj == null || boolVal)
```

In this case, "LoggedInMembershipUser" is just the Membership.GetUser(), "obj" is some random business object, and "boolVal" is obviously a boolean. When I write the statement as above, ReSharper tells me that the boolVal portion of the statement is always false. But when I put boolVal at the beginning as below, I don't get that notice.

```
if(boolVal|| LoggedInMembershipUser == null || obj == null)
```

Why would the first one always be false but the second one not?

EDIT: This is in the row data bind of a grid view. The grid is displaying results from two objects with the same base class, so "obj" will have a value if it's one of the object types but not the other. boolVal is an indicator for which type of object it is, so now that I think about it, I guess if obj is null then boolVal will always be true. Was ReSharper realizing that somehow? Oh I bet it was because looking at my code above the line I have:

```
if (!uploaded){
    var obj = GetObjectLogic();
}
```

Ok thanks for the help comments. I guess this can be voted to be deleted or whatever.

Comment: Is `boolVal` a local variable, a field, or a property? Same question for `obj` and `LoggedInMembershipUser`.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is short-circuiting.  Try using `|` instead of `||` and see if resharper still complains.

Comment: can you put a (short)test method together so we can see this in context.

Comment: @juharr a false in an OR statement will not force it to 'shortcircu't out of the logic, only a TRUE can do that. So resharper should not be saying it is always FALSE based off of how a OR statements work

Comment: I would actually recommend wrapping the `if around multiple `(` so that it can evaluate properly

Comment: @djkraze evaluating OR statements is kindve like the multiplicty rule in math. It doesnt matter what order it is evaluated in it will always have the same result

Comment: @gh9 Right, but if the null checks are true it doesn't get to the `boolVal` unless you move it to the front.

Comment: @juharr correct, if the null check is true and resharper sees that it shouldn't evaluate the statement to false.

Comment: The expression will be evaluated from left to right. If Resharper through analysis of earlier statements can determine that when LoggedInMembershipUser and obj are both not null, then boolVal will always be false, then Reshaper can warn about this.

Comment: @gh9 Let me repharse, it would be a combination of short-circuiting and `boolVal` being based on a null check of `obj` and\or `LoggedInMembershipUser`, like Oskar said.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without more of the method it is hard to know for sure, but it sure looks ike the following:

ReSharper has determined that the only way that `boolVal` can be true is if at least one of `LoggedInMembershipUser` or `obj` is null. That first `if` never reaches the `boolval` portion unless both are not null. Thus at the point where `boolVal` is evaluated it must be false.

If you reorder the conditions, then that logic no longer holds. ReSharper could potentially analyze that expression, determine that all parts are fast and side effect free, and notice that `boolVal` is not necessary in the second case too, but that analysis is somewhat harder and apparently has not been written.

Comment: Yeah this is what's going on. I realized it when I was creating the edit for my post.

Comment: Yeah and I noticed your edit right after I posted my answer. Go figure! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Every time I've investigated an unexpected `Expression is always true|false` scenario with ReSharper, the tool has proved smarter than me. For example, ReSharper is aware of inheritance trees; in this code block:

```
void doSomething(Object obj)
{
    if(obj is StreamReader || obj is TextReader)
        foo();
}
```

...ReSharper will mark `(obj is TextReader)` as `Expression is always false`, because the `(obj is StreamReader)` code branch will already have captured any `TextReader` objects and jumped to `foo()`, short-circuiting any further evaluation.